# C Global Struct Pointer

Tags: c, variables, pointers, struct, global-variables

I have a typedef'ed structure declared in a file. I have a pointer to it and want to use it in multiple files as a global variable.  Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

**fileA.h:**

```
typedef struct
{
  bool                  connected;
  char                  name[20];
}vehicle;

extern vehicle *myVehicle;
```

**fileA.c:**

```
#include "fileA.h"
void myFunction(){
    myVehicle = malloc(sizeof(vehicle));
    myVehicle->connected = FALSE;
}
```

**fileB.c:**

```
#include "fileA.h"
void anotherFunction(){
   strcpy(myVehicle->name, "this is my car");
}
```

The error I get is:

> Undefined external "myVehicle" referred to in fileA

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a *declaration*:

```
extern vehicle *myVehicle; /* extern makes this a declaration,
                              and tells the compiler there is
                              a definition elsewhere. */
```

Add a *definition*:

```
vehicle *myVehicle;
```

to *exactly* one `.c` file.

Comment: That worked. I could have sworn I tried that before and got a stack overflow. But perhaps I goofed.  Thanks hmjd!